# What's wrong with my RF amplifier? Transistor in parallel

Tags: transistors, amplifier, rf, frequency, parallel

Everything is OK with power consumption, no SWR or any wrong temperatures, but I'm not obtaining more than 900 mW. It's supposed to have 2 W and 30-35 dB.

The centered frequency is 2.4 GHz. The RF transistor is a [SKY65162](https://www.skyworksinc.com/-/media/SkyWorks/Documents/Products/401-500/SKY65162_70LF_201212K.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Why isn't pin 4 of the PA mentioned in the schematic?

Comment: SKY65162 its SOT-89 4-pin but the schematic doesn't automatically 4-pin because it's ground like the 2-pin

Comment: I suspected as much, but hiding pins of an IC in a schematic is very bad practice. It goes all the way back to the brain-damaged practice of hiding supply and ground pins of for example 74HC logic, then spamming all decoupling caps on the Vcc line instead of placing them next to the IC in the schematic to actually explain what they are for. Nothing good ever came out of hiding things. The natural follow-up question: is pin 4 grounded in the layout? How? The layout of these parts has to be done very carefully. Ideally the 5V should also be a filtered, dedicated RF supply.

Comment: @Dan show your calculations to justify the 2 watt power out into a 50 ohm load.

Comment: @Lundin ... because everyone knows drawing decoupling cap next to every gate makes a digital logic schematic clearer...

Comment: @user253751 No, everyone doesn't know that. The Internet is filled with bad schematics. (Also in case of logic gates etc you might have a layout where several gates have supply pins close to each other, so there's not necessarily always one cap per IC)

Comment: @user253751 I draw decoupling capacitors close to the chip they are used on and mark them up with a reference to that chip. Sometimes there isn't enough room and I make a block of them but, each capacitor will have a reference to the chip it's meant to be used on. Call it experience = the last ten years I've probably designed 40 PCBs and all worked 1st time (other than the odd component value change). This doesn't happen by accident; it happens because I pay **total attention** to every little detail and double check everything. Placement of caps in the schematic is something  I care about.

Comment: Are you sure that parallelling these devices(as done) ... will "outputs" be in "phase" ?

Answer (score 1):

For what follows, I going to assume your amplifiers have 50 ohm input and 50 ohm output impedances (as most RF devices should), and that your traces, or interconnects are 50 ohm impedance also.

So what you've drawn without splitters or combiners causes a 2:1 mismatch at the input to, and the outputs of the RF amplifiers.

Having 2 inputs, each one of 50 ohms impedance in parallel (I'm assuming they are close together) presents a load to the trace of 25 ohms.  Hence the 2:1 mismatch between the 50 ohms trace and two RF amplifier inputs.

A similar thing happens at the outputs of the RF amplifiers.

Hence you're throwing away a significant amount of power in mismatches.

As Wireless Learning said, you need to provide a properly designed & matched 1:2 splitter on the inputs, and a 2:1 combiner on the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

First thing one does not simply put two loads onto a source hoping power will get divided by magic.
Not often did I saw two amplifier in parallel like we do with power mosfets.

Architecture using multiple amplifiers in parallel generally use a power splitter between the two loads (your amplifiers) and more importantly phase shifters.
One amplifier is fed directly when the other signal is shifted of 90°. The output of the directly fed amplifier is shifted 90°, and then the output of the two amplifier is merged through a reversed power splitter.

You have chosen a very well documented RF amplifier, you should try to use the s parameters in QUCS STUDIO, to maximise the S11 of your system.
If this approach interest you I have simulations with this amplifier on QUCS STUDIO for you to use as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs of these amplifiers need DC isolation. Assuming that the decoupling and layout is reasonable, my suspicion is that making the DC connection between the two inputs is messing up the internal biassing.

.. and as others have said - you really need to sort out your impedance matching if you want to get close to datasheet performance.  That's unless you are working in a 25 ohm system.